# angularjs render based on response from REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-promise

I have an single app, which has a login button, as well as some other components. When I load the page, I have to make a call to authentication REST service and if authentication is disabled, I should not show the Login button. Similarly, I have to show the Login button, when the authentication is enabled.

As far as I have checked REST api calls are asynchronous and before the I get the response, the page gets loaded.

I even tried using promises as mentioned in the below link, but it couldn't help
http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/

How can I conditionally render the view based on the response from REST API call ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-if directive of angularjs. Update your scope variable on REST API response to make ng-if=true. This will create login button only when authentication done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show directive. based on the response of the authentication Api you can use show/hide the log-in button.

Answer (score 0):

First set one scope varible to false,use this varible to hide the login button.

```
$scope.loginButton = false;
```

You can use ng-show or ng-if directive to hide and show the html element.

```
<input type="submit" ng-show = "loginButton">
```

Call the REST services,you will get the response from service and then check the response.If authentication status is enabled then make scope variable to true.

```
$scope.loginButton = true;
```

Comment: I call the REST API in the init(). With ng-show, by the time I get response from REST api, the page is loaded and I see the login button. Even after, I get the response from the REST service and I change $scope.loginButton = false, i don't see the page updated and I still see the Login Button.

Comment: Declare a variable using $rootScope ,like $rootScope.loginButton = false before init() function.